# How to fit Markov Chain on price time series?

Tags: time-series, markov-process

Markov Chains usually deal with discrete states. But price time series is continuous.

Actually we will be considering not the time series itself, but its diffs:

```
continuous_diffs = [1.1, 1, 0.99, 1.01, ...]
```

so the price at time `t` will be `price(t = 7) = price(t = 0) * diff_1 * diff_2 * ... diff_6`.

It's possible to manually split continuous state into let's say 5 discrete states `huge_down, down, same, up, huge_up` so the diffs will be

```
continuous_diffs = [1.1,     1,    0.99, 1.01, ...]
discrete_diffs   = [huge_up, same, down, up, ...]
```

And now the serie is discrete and it's possible to fit Markov Chain.

But, **there are problems**. We need to find two parameters - number of states `K = 5` and the boundaries of those states. Should boundaries be evenly distributed, or maybe log-scale, or somehow else?

So, how to solve that? Ideally - **fit Continuous Markov Chain** (if it exists). Or tell Markov Chain number of states `K = 5` and **Markov Chain somehow himself find the optimal discrete boundaries**.

Are there such algorithms? Or executable examples, notebooks?